# XML - entity references versus encoding

Tags: xml, encoding, entityreference

What is the difference between encoding and entity references in xml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encoding refers to the way a character is represented by a sequence of bytes. It happens at a pretty low level in the processing chain: you read in the bytes and use the encoding to convert to a stream of characters. ASCII, Latin-1, and UTF-8 are all examples of encodings.

Entity references are handled by the XML parser itself. A sequence of characters, starting with `&` and ending with `;`, is used to represent a different sequence of characters (usually just one). This happens at a fairly high level, conceptually "after" the XML parser has determined where tags are. This is why `&lt;` turns into a plain old less than sign, not the beginning of a tag.

Comment: so if i replace '%' with '&#37;' is that encoding or entity reference?

Comment: @SoftwareGeek That's an entity reference. The word "encoding" could also be used to describe an entity reference in the sense that it is a way of "encoding" things in the English language sense, but normally when people use the word encoding in this sort of context they mean a character encoding, which this isn't.